# Passing a password to an Automator application

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, password

I have written an Automator application with the following shell script to open an FTP connection on my system:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display alert "SFTP Opened"'
```

This works exactly as expected except that the **sudo** command needs a password. When the same command is run on Terminal, it prompts me for a password but when run as an Automator app, doesn't prompt me for any input. Is there anyway to programmatically pass the password to this sudo within the Automator script? I know this is not a safe practice but I still want to do it as my system is reasonably secure and untouched by anyone other than me.

A "do shell script...with administrator privileges" method is giving the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AppleScript should let you do this by using `with administrator privileges`:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist" with administrator privileges'
```

This doesn't pass the password, but prompts for it with a standard OS X prompt:

[image]

You can use this in your Automator workflow in one of the two following ways:

[image]

Comment: @Amit osascript is for bash :) If you want pure AppleScript in the AppleScript Automator action, remove the osascript like this: `do shell script "sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist" with administrator privileges` ([Do one of the following from this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/93lLV.png))

Comment: Yes, this worked like charm! Thanks for your patience...silly me!

Answer (score 3):

## expect

You could instead use a tool like [expect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html) to script the interaction with `sudo`. `expect` is designed for this situation.

> expect - programmed dialogue with interactive programs

The following shell script may be enough for your two commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
send "my-secret-password\n"
```

## AppleScript and with administrator privileges

An alternative approach is to use AppleScript's **do shell script** command. The command offers a **with administrator privileges** option. Apple's [Technical Note 2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) covers do shell script in detail.

## echo

Other common approaches to this problem involve using `echo` to pass the password to `sudo` with a pipe. This StackOverflow answer discusses this and other related approaches, [How to provide password to a command that prompts for one in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857702/how-to-provide-password-to-a-command-that-prompts-for-one-in-bash)